# Problem with uninstalling Ubuntu 22.04 version on Win 11 (WSL)

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What I've done is follow the steps from

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview

Then I decided to uninstall the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS application from my PC (and restart PC).
Then uninstall Windows subsystem for Linux Preview (and restart).
However the penguin on my explorer continued to persist. There was no folder with Ubuntu system files. So I thought I was half OK (at least I didn't have something eating my HDD).

The problem came after that, when I downloaded instead of the 22.04 version I downloaded the 20.04 version, keeping in mind that it should be more stable cause it was simply older.

Now I have on my PC 20.04 and 22.04 from where did 22.04 come ? On apps and features settings (win11) there is no 22.04 LS Ubuntu.

My question is how to remove-uninstall-delete permanently the 22.04 version?

Comment: Was there a problem with 22.04 as you state that 20.04 is more stable.

Comment: @David I'm generally speaking.

Comment: There is no basis for that statement.

Comment: @David We are going out of context. Do you have solution in mind or not ?